# Failed to load plugin GStreamer

Tags: mingw, gstreamer, glib, msys2

Have a plugin in gstreamer.
When i try use gst-inpect plugin_name, i get message:

```
(gst-inspect-1.0:6840): GStreamer-WARNING **: 08:35:23.841: Failed to load plugin 'C:\msys64\usr\local\lib\gstreamer-1.0\plugin_name.dll' 
This usually means Windows was unable to find a DLL dependency of the plugin. Please check that PATH is correct. 
You can run 'dumpbin -dependents' (provided by the Visual Studio developer prompt) to list the DLL deps of any DLL.
```

There are also some third-party GUIs to list and debug DLL dependencies recursively.

I check dll use ldd and dumpbin. Also check recursive dependence. After research i found g_module_open return NULL, and %errorlevel% is empty.

How can find reason why failed to load plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Check the dependencies using `dumpbin -dependents C:\msys64\usr\local\lib\gstreamer-1.0\plugin_name.dll`  command 
And also check all the dependencies files are present in **C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin**

This type of error may also occur if GStreamer is properly not installed.
Make sure after installing GStreamer you add all 3 paths in the environment variable.
`C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin`, `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib`, and `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include`

Answer (score 0):

Check if opening `C:\msys64\usr\local\lib\gstreamer-1.0\plugin_name.dll` with [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) reports any issues and make sure you are not mixing architectures (Windows 32-bit and 64-bit).