Stream OpenCv frames as video pipeline with Gstreamer
I have to read frames from RealSense camera and make an RTSP server to stream frames as video, so other clients (multiple) can be able to see the video.
Platform: Windows10.
For doing so it seems that I have to use Gstreamer backend of OpenCv VideoWriter.
I have done the following steps.

Rebuild OpenCv with Gstreamer backend
Install Gstreamer MSVC 64-bit (VS 2019, Release CRT) runtime and development packages.
Write a simple Python program to test OpenCv + Gstreamer

Seems that Gstreamer can't load plugins event if I have added Gstreamer bin folder and Gstreamer plugin folder.
Sample Python program
import os
os.add_dll_directory("C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\msvc_x86_64\\bin")
os.add_dll_directory("C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\msvc_x86_64\\lib\\gstreamer-1.0")
import cv2 as cv
import numpy
 
sourceUrl = "http://pendelcam.kip.uni-heidelberg.de/mjpg/video.mjpg"
#command = "appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=5004 host=127.0.0.1 "
command = "appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink port=5004 host=127.0.0.1 auto-multicast=0"
 
cap = cv.VideoCapture(sourceUrl)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Capture Not Opened")
 
writer = cv.VideoWriter(command, cv.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, 30, (1280, 720), True)
if not writer.isOpened():
    print("WRITER NOT OPENED!!!!!")
 
if cap.isOpened() and writer.isOpened():
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Not Fram received")
            break
        cv.imshow("frame", frame)
        writer.write(frame)
        if cv.waitKey(1) > 0:
            break
   
    cap.release()
    writer.release()

Error output
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:18:56.512: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\gstx264.dll': The specified module could not be found.
This usually means Windows was unable to find a DLL dependency of the plugin. Please check that PATH is correct.
You can run 'dumpbin -dependents' (provided by the Visual Studio developer prompt) to list the DLL deps of any DLL.
There are also some third-party GUIs to list and debug DLL dependencies recursively.
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.512: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:18:56.512: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type '<invalid>'
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.512: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.512: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.512: g_object_class_find_property: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT_CLASS (class)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.512: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.512: g_type_class_unref: assertion 'g_class != NULL' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:18:56.512: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\gstvideoparsersbad.dll': The specified module could not be found.
This usually means Windows was unable to find a DLL dependency of the plugin. Please check that PATH is correct.
You can run 'dumpbin -dependents' (provided by the Visual Studio developer prompt) to list the DLL deps of any DLL.
There are also some third-party GUIs to list and debug DLL dependencies recursively.
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.512: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:18:56.525: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type '<invalid>'
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.526: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.526: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:18:56.530: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\gstvideoparsersbad.dll': The specified module could not be found.
This usually means Windows was unable to find a DLL dependency of the plugin. Please check that PATH is correct.
You can run 'dumpbin -dependents' (provided by the Visual Studio developer prompt) to list the DLL deps of any DLL.
There are also some third-party GUIs to list and debug DLL dependencies recursively.
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.531: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.532: g_type_class_unref: assertion 'g_class != NULL' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:18:56.535: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\gstrtp.dll': The specified module could not be found.
This usually means Windows was unable to find a DLL dependency of the plugin. Please check that PATH is correct.
You can run 'dumpbin -dependents' (provided by the Visual Studio developer prompt) to list the DLL deps of any DLL.
There are also some third-party GUIs to list and debug DLL dependencies recursively.
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.537: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:18:56.537: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type '<invalid>'
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.539: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.540: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.540: g_object_class_find_property: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT_CLASS (class)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.541: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.541: g_type_class_unref: assertion 'g_class != NULL' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:18:56.545: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\gstudp.dll': The specified module could not be found.
This usually means Windows was unable to find a DLL dependency of the plugin. Please check that PATH is correct.
You can run 'dumpbin -dependents' (provided by the Visual Studio developer prompt) to list the DLL deps of any DLL.
There are also some third-party GUIs to list and debug DLL dependencies recursively.
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.546: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:18:56.547: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type '<invalid>'
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.548: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.549: gst_element_factory_get_element_type: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_FACTORY (factory)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.551: g_object_class_find_property: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT_CLASS (class)' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.552: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
 
(python.exe:6512): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:18:56.553: g_type_class_unref: assertion 'g_class != NULL' failed
[ WARN:0@1.151] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:2436 cv::CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: error opening writer pipeline: no property "speed-preset" in element "x264enc"


Looks like same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726543/failed-to-load-plugin-gstreamer
So check if you have these paths set in environment variables
C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib\  C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin\ C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\include\ 
Also, its understandable that you are new to gstreamer but try to go through error logs and try searching for specific error before posting the question. :)

Hi @Akkshay, Be sure that I have been trying so much time and reading on the Internet how to solve it ;) Adding this paths to Path environment variable seems to work! Also works if you copy all dlls from msvc_x86_64\bin to msvc_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0 It's not a good idea but I tried before your reply because I seen that plugins depends on gstreamer dlls with DependencyWalker
